# Batch files runs over half only?

Tags: python

I have come across this puzzling problem in Python, where I am running this script to iterate over files and pull out the line with the highest value in index position 6. For some reason, when I run this, it only iterates over about half the files only.

This is the code:

```
output=open("max.txt","w")

from glob import glob
for filename in glob("*bam.txt"):
    file=open(filename,"r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    max=0   

    for i in range(0,len(lines)+1): 
        if i<len(lines):
            newlines=lines[i].replace("\n","\t")
            splitted=newlines.split("\t")
            if int(splitted[6])>int(max):
                max=splitted[6]
                index=i
        elif i==len(lines):
            output.write(filename+"\t"+lines[index])
        else:
            print("There is an error!")

output.close()
```

And this is an error message I receive at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I specifically have `len(lines)+1` as the end of my range because I know it would be excluded and if I only had `len(lines)`, then `i` would never equal `len(lines)` and thus nothing would be written to output.

Many thanks!

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from `splitted[6]`; in other words, one of the lines doesn't have seven fields in it.

Comment: Or it's the `lines[index]` line; OP it would be helpful to call out which line in your code is `line 15`, since that's what your traceback is pointing to. Otherwise we have to guess, since the 15th line in your post is `index=i` which would clearly not cause this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the content of one of the sample files or point exactly which line is line 15?

Comment: line 15 is indeed:
`output.write(filename+"\t"+lines[index])`

Comment: @jasonharper is there a way to confirm that all my lines contain seven fields? I tried `if splitted[6] == ""` but found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason your code fails is because you are not resetting `index` on each file. So if file 1 had a max on line 10, but file 2 only has 7 lines, you might run into the error where your index is out of range. On the second file `i` might refer to `len(lines)`, which is 7, but `index` to 9.

Your whole condition inside the loop is quite redundant to be honest. What you probably want instead:

```
(...)
line_with_max=0
max=0
for i in range(0, len(lines)): 
    newlines=lines[i].replace("\n","\t")
    splitted=newlines.split("\t")
    if int(splitted[6]) > max:
        max=int(splitted[6])
        line_with_max=i
output.write(filename+"\t"+lines[line_with_max])
(...)
```

Comment: I see, I forgot to reset the index as it loops through the files. This makes a lot of sense. Still learning, thank you!